# Pipeline in Azure Devops using Task "Invoke Rest API" is failing Error:"<>.yml (Line: 1, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the Task for the first time in Azure Devops.

```
- task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
    serviceConnection: 'Deploy'
    method: 'POST'
    headers: |
      {
      "Content-Type":"application/json", 
      "x-api-key": "<<>>", 
      "Authorization": "<<>>", 
      }
    body: |
      {
        "componentId": "<<>>",
        "packageVersion":"<<>>",
        "shareable":"false"
      }
    urlSuffix: 'package/create/'
    waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

Comment: Can you share your full yaml?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk  the yaml content is already shown above. I am just trying to deploy a package by using the task "InvokeRESTAPI". the Build for the pipeline is failing.

Answer (score 1):

> Pipeline in Azure Devops using Task “Invoke Rest API” is failing Error:“<>.yml (Line: 1, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected”

According to the state of the [Invoke REST API task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops), we could to know:

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to **invoke an HTTP API**
>   and parse the response.

And

> **The Invoke REST API task does not perform deployment actions directly**. Instead, it allows you to invoke any generic HTTP REST API
>   as part of the automated pipeline and, optionally, wait for it to be
>   completed.
>
> For more information about using this task, see [Approvals and gates
>   overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops).

So, we could **NOT** use this task in the `build`/`release` pipeline directly. And we could search this task in the [Azure devops marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=invoke&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance). It always used for the Approvals and gates in the release pipeline:

[image]

To deploy the package, we could use the corresponding deployment task, like [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops), [Azure App Service deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, why could it *NOT* be used in a build/release pipeline?  It's just a generic tool to make any HTTP REST API call.